# $T:R^3 \rightarrow R^3$. Show that there is a line L such that $T(L) =L$.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let $T:R^3 \rightarrow R^3$
be a linear transformation. Show that there is a line L
such that $T(L) =L$.

My Idea:

So the characteristic equation would be a cubic polynomial hence there is at least one real root.

Hence we are guaranteed of one eigen vector say $u$.

Consider the subspace generated by the vector $u$, $\{\beta u  |  \beta \epsilon  \mathbb{R}\}$. This is a the required Line $L$ such that$T(L) = L$.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I am not sure about the correctness of the proof and since I am appearing for graduate exams would welcome any new idea, thanks

Comment: No worries, you got it right.

Comment: What about $T=\begin{pmatrix} 0&0&0\\0&0&-1\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: @Lem.ma corresponding to eigenvalue 0 we have the eigen vector (1,0,0) so no worries, the subspace generated by this eigen vector will be the required line L.

Comment: As it stands (with $T(L)=L$ the claim is not correct (and  the matrix in the comment of @Lem.ma as well as $T=0$ provide a counter examples). With $T(L)\subset L$ it is just existence of an eigenvalue.

Comment: @AndreasCap thanks for the insight.. so the question needs to be modified?....... So if the non singular matrices were considered for T then I guess T(L) = L, would hold?

Comment: Yes, you can either assume $T$ is non-singular and prove $T(L)=L$ or make no assumption and prove $T(L)\subset L$. The argument you give works in both cases, but if the only eigenvalue is zero (which is the case for the matrix in the comment by @Lem.ma) then it also shows that  $T(L)\subset L$.